# Determine if, within a post, you are on page 2 or greater - Wordpress documentation circular

Tags: functions, paged

I am trying to run a function that executes only on the first page of any post. So, if a post is paginated because you have used the `<!--nextpage-->` tag and you are on page 2 or greater of that article, then the function should not run.

[Even the Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Paged_Page) is confused how to do this:

> When the page being displayed is "paged". This refers to an archive or
> the main page being split up over several pages and will return true
> on 2nd and subsequent pages of posts. This does not refer to a Post or
> Page whose content has been divided into pages using the
> nextpage QuickTag. To check if a Post or Page has been divided
> into pages using the nextpage QuickTag, see [A_Paged_Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Paged_Page)
> section.

Further details:

I currently use the following code in my functions.php to move my featured image within posts from the default position above the first paragraph and below the title, to underneath the first paragraph.

The problem is that it also shows the featured image, in the same spot, on pages 2, 3, 4, etc of the same article (when I have used `<!--nextpage-->`). The featured image should only show on the first page of any article.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_feat_image', 20 );
function insert_feat_image( $content ) {
if (!is_single(array(xxxxx))) {
  global $post;
  if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $caption = 'xxxx';
    $img = 'xxx';
    $content = xxx;
  }
  return $content;
}  else {
    $contentnormal = preg_replace('#(<p>.*?</p>)#','$1'.$img . $caption, $content, 1);}
     return $contentnormal;
}
```

I removed some potentially identifying code that is not relevant to this question (xxx).

Comment: Did you mean paginated using the `<!--nextpage-->` tag? Where/when are you trying to run your function - in The Loop, on page load, or? And what does your function do?

Comment: Sally and me are both still confused, please re-edit your question to describe your issue clearly and simply as possible. `executes only on the first page of any post` statement is very conflicting... first page of any post??? where are we running this function?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ and joshmoto I added more detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that it also shows the featured image, in the same
> spot, on pages 2, 3, 4, etc of the same article (when I have used
> `<!--nextpage-->`). The featured image should only show on the first
> page of any article.

In that case, then this might work for you:

```php
function insert_feat_image( $content ) {
    global $page, $multipage;

    if ( $multipage && $page <= 1 ) {
        // it's the 1st page, so run your code here.
    } // else, it's not paginated or not the 1st page

    return $content;
}
```

Explanation about the global variables above:

1. `$multipage` is a boolean flag indicating whether the page/post is paginated using the `<!--nextpage-->` tag (or the [Page Break block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/page-break-block/) in Gutenberg), and the flag would be a *true*, as long as the post contains the `<!--nextpage-->` tag and that the global post data has already been setup, e.g. [`the_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/) or [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) has been called. (which is true when inside The Loop)
2. The page number is stored in `$page`, but the number can also be retrieved using `get_query_var( 'page' )`. (yes, it's `page` and *not* `paged`)

### Alternate Solution

If you just wanted to know whether it's the first page or not, regardless how the page/post was paginated (and **only if** it was paginated or in the case of archives, it means there are more than one page of results), you can try this instead which should work on *any pages* (single Post/Page/CPT, category archives, search results pages, etc.):

```php
function insert_feat_image( $content ) {
    global $page, $multipage, $paged, $wp_query;

    $page_num = max( 1, $page, $paged );
    /* Or you can use:
    $page_num = max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ), get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    */

    if ( ( $multipage || $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) && $page_num <= 1 ) {
        // it's the 1st page, so run your code here.
    } // else, it's not paginated or not the 1st page

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your first solution worked! I just removed the ``$multipage`` part, because I need it to work on whether or not the page has ``<!--nextpage-->`` or not (which is what I think your 2nd solution is about?). But the the first one worked, thank you, and I learned about ``$page``.

Comment: Yes, both the solutions check if the page/post is actually paginated. And it did cross my mind that you just wanted to know how to check if the page number is 1 or more, but anyway, I'm glad my answer helped :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to determine if a singular `single.php` post page is on a `paged()` page number then this will require a little more logic.

But if you are simply trying execute a function if a post is on an archive page one... then this should be pretty straight forward doing this...

```php
<?=
// args
$args = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1
];

// setup query
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This will detect what page your are on with above query...

```php
<?php

// if above query page number is 1
if($query['paged'] === 1 ) {

  // do stuff

}
```

Hopefully makes sense. Let me know if not.

Comment: Thank you for this, but when I enter the first block into functions.php, I get this error re the last line 'setup query' `syntax error, unexpected variable "$query"`

Comment: After `$args = []` you need `;` to close.

Comment: Hi @joshmoto I added more detail to the question